almacenar los datos del formulario antes de guardar en php
Buenas tardees con tod@s, en la siguiente imagen tengo un formulario que hice en php, este proporciona al usuario almacenar su produccion diaria para el control de sus procesos.
lo que quiero hacer en este formulario es ingresar la informacion y se vaya agregando en bandeja (el cuarpo del formulario "tipo de produccion, fondo documental, descripcion y cantidad") como un datagrid, este al llenarse en la tabla se enumera, una vez que el usuario ha terminado de llenar su producción se coloca en el boton guardar y se va a las sus tablas respectivas cabecera (nombrem, sede y fecha), cuerpo (tipo de produccion, fondo documental, descripcion, cantidad), el evento es de una sola cabecera muchos cuerpos.

codigo del formulario:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> 
   <title>Menu Principal</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    session_start();

    if(empty($_SESSION["cod_usr"]))
    {
        header("location: ../login.php");
    }

 include ("../includes/MasterPage.inc.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION["bandeja"])) $_SESSION["bandeja"] = [];
echo '<div>';
if(isset($_GET["status"]))
{
    if($_GET["status"] === "1")
    {
        echo '<table align="center" width="100">
                <tr align="center">
                    <td class="Error">
                        <strong>Error:</strong> No se puede ingresar un tipo de producto vasio
                    </td>
                </tr>
              </table>';
    }
    if($_GET["status"] === "2")
    {
        echo '<table align="center" width="100">
                <tr align="center">
                    <td class="Error">
                        <strong>Error:</strong> No se puede ingresar un tipo de producto vasio
                    </td>
                </tr>
              </table>';
    }
    if($_GET["status"] === "3")
    {
        echo '<table align="center" width="100">
                <tr align="center">
                    <td class="Confirmacion">
                        <strong>Correcto:</strong>
                    </td>
                </tr>
              </table>';
    }
}
 echo '</div>';
 
?>
    <div>
    </div>
    
        <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" action="">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="tituloLogin" align="center">REGISTRO DE PRODUCCION</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" class="lineaBlanca" height="1px">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          <tr align="center">
            <td colspan="2">
              <table width="1060" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="auto-style1" style="border-color: black; border-style:solid; padding: .2em;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <input class="botonFormulario1" name="btngrabar" type="button" value="GUARDAR">
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <input name="btncancelar" class="botonFormulario1" type="button" value="ELIMINAR" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
              </table>
                <form method="post" action="../includes/AgregarTabla.inc.php">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="1060" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="auto-style1" style="border-color: black; border-style:solid;">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5" align="center" style="height: 20px; color:#000000; ">DATOS GENERALES DE LA PRODUCCIÓN</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5" style="height: 8px; background-color: #FFFFFF;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5" height="2"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="13%" align="right" class="label">Sede:</td>
                            <td width="40%"><?php echo '
                            <input name="sede" type="text" id="sede" style="width: 220px; height: 6px;" class="cajaTexto" value = "' ?> <?php echo $_SESSION["sede"]; ?> <?php echo '" />'?>
                            </td>
                            <td width="8%" align="right" class="label">Fecha:</td>
                            <td colspan="2"><?php echo '
                            <input name="txtfecha" type="text" id="fecha" style="width: 100px; height: 6px;" class="cajaTexto" readonly="readonly" value = "' ?> <?php echo $_SESSION["fechahoy"]; ?> <?php echo '" />'?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5" height="2"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td align="right" class="label">Tipo de Producción:</td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                                <select name='cbtp' style='width: 450px; height: 24px;' class='combo'>
                            <?php
                                include ("../includes/tipo_produccion.inc.php");

                                echo "<option sytle='color: #333333;' value=''>";
                                while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($reg))
                                {
                                    echo "<option sytle='color: #333333;' value='".$row['id']."'>" .$row['descripcion']."";
                                }
                                echo "</select>";
                            ?>
                        </td>     
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5" height="2"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" class="label">Fondo Documental:</td>
                            <td colspan="4">
                                <?php
                                    include ("../includes/fondo_documental.inc.php");

                                    echo "<select name='cbfd' id='cbfd' style='width: 780px; height: 24px;' class='combo'>";
                                    echo "<option sytle='color: #333333;' value=''>";
                                    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($reg))
                                    {
                                        echo "<option sytle='color: #333333;' value='".$row['id']."'>" .$row['descripcion']."";
                                    }
                                    echo "</select>";
                                ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5" height="2"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" class="label">Descripción:</td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="Caleli" type="text" id="caleli" style="width: 350px; height: 6px;" class="cajaTexto">
                            </td>
                            <td width="8%" align="right" class="label">Cantidad:</td>
                            <td width="8%">
                                <input name="cant" type="text" id="cant" style="width: 90px; height: 6px;" class="cajaTexto">
                            </td>
                            <td width="22%" align="center">
                                <!--input class="botonFormulario2" type="button" name="btnagregar" id="btnagregar" value="Agregar"-->
                                <button type="submit" class="botonFormulario2" name="btnagregar" >Agregar</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5" height="2"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="1060" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="auto-style1" style="border-color: black; border-style:solid;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF; background-color: #000066">N°</td>
                        <td align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF; background-color: #000066">Código Cabecera</td>
                        <td align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF; background-color: #000066">Código Produccion</td>
                        <td align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF; background-color: #000066">Código F.Doc</td>
                        <td align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF; background-color: #000066">Descripcion</td>
                        <td align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF; background-color: #000066">Cantidad</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="center">
            <td colspan="2">
            </td>
          </tr>         
        </table>
</body>


Saludos. Omites incluir el error que estás obteniendo (en Frontend y/o Backend) así como (en lo posible) el código donde se genera el error.

hice uno array pero lo eliminé así que el codigo esta para incluir una nueva logica por así desirlo, soy nuevo en esto
